# Cannot load a SolverResults object with bad status: error

Tags: python, optimization, error-handling, pyomo, gurobi

Does anyone know what this error message means?
I tried looking in old conversations, but they had used different solvers so it seems like I need to use another method.
I run an optimization problem with pyomo in python with the solver gurobi.

My full error message:

File "C:\Users\frida.spyder-py3\26 january\optimization.py", line 183, in 
solver.solve(m, tee=True)

File "C:\Users\frida\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\solvers\plugins\solvers\direct_solver.py", line 183, in solve
default_variable_value=self._default_variable_value)

File "C:\Users\frida\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\PyomoModel.py", line 226, in load_from
% str(results.solver.status))

ValueError: Cannot load a SolverResults object with bad status: error

Comment: Try just catching and printing the results….  You may get more insight…. 
`results = solver.solve(…)`
`print(results)`

Answer (score 1):

ValueError: Cannot load a SolverResults object with bad status: error. This means that it is not possible to access the solution.
Your problem is either infeasible or unbounded, or a solution does not exist.

According to [pyomo documentation](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/model_debugging/model_interrogation.html), you can see the output of your solver with the option `tee=True` to the solver

`SolverFactory('glpk').solve(model, tee=True)`

Also you can use `pprint`to see your model or variables

```
model.pprint()
model.x.pprint()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).